# How to find java total heap memory consumed by classes in specific package using heapdump

Tags: java, heap-memory, heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

Using heapdump, how to find the total heap memory consumed by all the instances of classes under a specific package.

Example, would like to know how much heap memory was consumed by `org.apache.log4j.*` This should certainly include the String, HashMap, primitive datatypes, etc. used by log4j

Tried Eclipse Memory Analyzer MAT but couldn't find the total heap memory used for particular package. MAT excludes "not reachable objects" in it's histogram view.